# (Android) PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher not formatting number if user deletes "-" or "(" or ")"

Tags: android

I am using PhoneNumberFormattingTextWathcer to format the mobile number and it's working fine.
But if I am deleting "-" or "(" or ")", number is not formatting again.

I am using below code:

```
 editPrimarynumber.addTextChangedListener(
        PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("US")
    )
```

Deleting numbers from right end, works fine.
Please help to resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Formatter.

```
editPrimarynumber.addTextChangedListener(PhoneTextFormatter(editPrimarynumber,"(###) ###-####"));
```

**PhoneText Formatter**

```
 class PhoneTextFormatter(private val mEditText: EditText, private val mPattern: String) :
    TextWatcher {
    private val tag = this.javaClass.simpleName
    override fun beforeTextChanged(
        s: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        count: Int,
        after: Int
    ) {
        // do nothing
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(
        s: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        before: Int,
        count: Int
    ) {
        val phone = StringBuilder(s)
        Log.d(tag, "join")
        if (count > 0 && !isValid(phone.toString())) {
            for (i in 0 until phone.length) {
                Log.d(tag, String.format("%s", phone))
                val c = mPattern[i]
                if (c != '#' && c != phone[i]) {
                    phone.insert(i, c)
                }
            }
            mEditText.setText(phone)
            mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.text.length)
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) { // do nothing
    }

    private fun isValid(phone: String): Boolean {
        for (i in 0 until phone.length) {
            val c = mPattern[i]
            if (c == '#') continue
            if (c != phone[i]) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    init {
        //set max length of string
        val maxLength = mPattern.length
        mEditText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(LengthFilter(maxLength))
    }
}
```

Comment: Still if I delete "(" or ")", formatting is not proper.